# Adding an integer data type value to a pointer but not a double

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having a little trouble understanding the following question.

"Given that a pointer holds the value of a memory address, why is it permitted to add an integer data type to a pointer variable but not a double data type."

I've got a feeling it may have something to do with address sizes? but I'm struggling with the mechanics of pointers right now =[

Comment: Are you from a country where non-integer addresses, like "Queen's Road 2.74" or "3.14159265, Elm Street", are common?

Comment: Because you can't address a memory block at position 3,1415

@molbdnilo: Damn, 20 seconds faster than me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't point to half a byte. Or 0.099999999998 of one. It's as simple as that. It makes no sense to have a non-integral value of a memory address, which is why such nonsensical operation is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, nothing to do with address sizes. It's more to do with precision. A floating point number is not precise where an integer is exact, by definition.

It's a bit like comparing latitude and longitude to residential address. Which would you put on a letter??? ... it's called a memory *address* for a reason ;-)